# Can the eigenvalues of a real symmetric tensor be complex?

Tags: linear-algebra, random-matrices, eigenvalues, multilinear-algebra, tensor

Let $T$ be a fully symmetric tensor of rank $3$ and size $N$.

Using the following definition of eigenvalues, let $x\in \mathbb{C}^N$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ such that:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{jk}^NT_{ijk}x_kx_j=\lambda x_i
\label{eq1}
\end{equation}
with the constraint that $\sum_i x_i^2=1$.

In the literature [1] (top of page 4) it is said that the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors can be complex. I completely fail to see this. Here is my reasoning:

Since $T$ is fully symmetric, for all $i$, $j$, $k$ we have $T_{ijk}=T_{jki}=\dots=T_{kji}$. Let me define the matrix $M$ such that:
\begin{equation}
M_{ij}=\sum_k^N T_{ijk}x_k.
\end{equation}
Due to the symmetry of $T$, my matrix $M$ is also symmetric and the first equation can now be written as:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j}^NM_{ij}x_j=\lambda x_i.
\end{equation}
All $\lambda$ and all $x$ are real since $M$ is symmetric. Therefore $T$ cannot have complex eigenvalues.

Is this correct? if not, could we find a counter-example? (for $N=3$ or $4$ for example)

[1] [Gurau - On the generalization of the Wigner semicircle law to real symmetric tensors](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.02660).

Comment: Thanks. Based on your example, if $T$ only has real components and is fully symmetric, then my argument with $M$ still holds and complex eigenvectors and eigenvalues are still impossible, no?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, $M$ is only *real* symmetric if you've already assumed $x$ is a real vector. A complex symmetric matrix can certainly have non-real eigenvalues.

Comment: @Malkoun, although it's not explicitly stated in the body, the title question indicates that the question is about *real* $T$, so the natural [example](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/384098/can-the-eigenvalues-of-a-real-symmetric-tensor-be-complex/384129#comment977880_384098) you propose doesn't qualify.  Indeed, if $T$ is real then $T(e_1, e_1)$ will also be real.

Comment: I misread. I will delete my comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a counter example of a complex eigenvector: $N=3$, the nonzero elements of $T$ are $T_{111}=2$, $T_{122}=T_{212}=T_{221}=1$, $T_{133}=T_{313}=T_{331}=1$. Eigenvectors with eigenvalue $2$ are $x=(1,iz,z)$, for any $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

(The flaw in the argument of the OP is indicated by [@lambda](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/384098/can-the-eigenvalues-of-a-real-symmetric-tensor-be-complex#comment977922_384098): it *assumes* the eigenvector is real, which as this counter example shows need not be the case.)

Comment: Isn't the original question about a complex *eigenvalue*, not just a complex *eigenvector* with real eigenvalue?

Comment: well, the argument provided by the OP implies both real eigenvalues _and_ real eigenvectors for any real symmetric $T$; this counterexample invalidates that, doesn't it?

Comment: @ZachTeitler, ah, good point!  So, for example, a much cheaper example:  even just $T_{111} = 1$ and all other entries equal $0$ has $\sum T_{i j k}x_k x_j = \lambda x_i$, where $x_1 = \lambda$ and all other entries equal $0$.

Comment: @LSpice --- in that "cheap" example, the condition $\sum_i x_i^2=1$ forces $\lambda=\pm 1$; and it would also force $t=\pm 1$ in Zach Teitler's example.

Comment: @ZachTeitler - the paper cited by the OP explicitly stresses that $x^2 =1$ is intended, not $\bar{x} x=1$.

Comment: ah, that is a well known issue, there is no unique definition of an eigenvalue/eigenvector for a tensor; I am not sure one definition is more natural than another.

Comment: Ah, good, I missed the $\sum x_i^2 = 1$ condition.  But still, doesn't this counterexample only show that the argument is wrong, not explicitly (yet) that a real symmetric tensor can have complex eigenvalues?

Comment: @ZachTeitler - OP is explicitly interested in the paper he cites, and there the normalization happens to be $x^2 =1$. We may deplore it, but that's what the OP is looking for.

Comment: I would be interested in a definition of eigenvalues and eigenvectors that entails only real eigenvalues for a symmetric tensor. If there is any references regarding eigenvalues of tensors you find interesting I would be grateful to hear more about it.

Comment: I deleted my comments.

Comment: A lot of this discussion was my repeated mistakes, and you and others correcting me. I'm sorry if I acted rashly, but I didn't feel like my thoughtless errors were a positive contribution, and frankly I'm a little embarrassed.

Comment: understood, I will delete my last comment.

Answer (score 6):

Let us take $n=2$. Let $T_{112} = T_{121} = T_{211} = 1$, $T_{222} = \frac{43}{9}$ and $T_{ijk} = 0$ otherwise. Consider the vector

$\mathbf{x} = \left( \begin{array}{c} \frac{5}{4} \\ i \frac{3}{4} \end{array} \right)$.

Then, unless I made a calculation mistake, $\mathbf{x}$ is an eigenvector of $T$, whose sum of the squares of its components is $1$, and with eigenvalue

$\lambda = i\frac{3}{2},$

which is complex and not real.

Comment: I deleted my comments.